# formal proof from calulus

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-writing

Given $f:R \to R$, $f$ is differentiable on $R$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(-x))=0$.
I need to show that there is $x_0 \in R$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$

I am trying to prove it by contradiction .... so i assume there is no $x_0 \in R$ such that  $f'(x_0)=0$ this means this function is strictly monotonic because the derivative "respects" the mean value theorem so it cannot be negative and positive without passing a zero value .... 
(from what i understand the derivative function of a continuous/differentiable functions isn't necessarily continuous but it still respect the mean value theorem i think it's called darboux's theorem )

now from $\lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-f(-x))=0$ ,we get $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}f(-x)$

now the last step is the contradiction its very intuitive and even maybe obvious that we can't get $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty}f(-x)$ for strictly monotonic function but i cant think of a formal way to prove it .

Comment: Don't forget about the case $f(x) \equiv cost$

Comment: you can *not* deduce $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = \lim_{x\to\infty} f(-x)$ Take $f(x)=x^2$ as a counterexample.

Comment: thanks for editing . i don't think its a good counterexample its not from R to R and the argument still holds for this function . but i can be wrong .... :D

Comment: My instinct here would be to look at the proof of Rolle's theorem and work out how to modify it to obtain this result. (I'd actually *do* this but unfortunately I have to leave my house now!)

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 aren't both limits equal to $+\infty$?

Comment: Clive i'm almost sure you're right i even tried to do it but all i manged to get from it is there exists a point that arbitrary close to zero ...... but i don't think that its good enough.             -dani_s i think its only one of the many options .....

Comment: A counterexample to the limits existing is $f(x) = \cos x$.

Comment: -Hurkyl nice counterexample

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$. Since $g(0)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$, $g$ is either identically $0$ or it has a local maximum or minimum at $x_0\in(0,\infty)$. In the same way it was shown for Rolle's Theorem, we have that $g'(x_0)=0$. Thus,
$$
f'(x_0)+f'(-x_0)=0
$$
If $f'$ is not identically $0$ and $x_0\ne0$, apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Comment: it took me some time to digest your proof but your absolutely right . thanks for help .

Answer (score 1):

Although I feel that robjohn's answer is much simpler and better, I am providing an alternative proof.

Suppose that $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then since derivatives possess intermediate value property, $f'(x)$ is of constant sign. Let's take the case when $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$ (the case $f'(x) < 0$ can be handled similarly). Clearly $f(x)$ is increasing everywhere and hence either $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = \infty$. Also now $f(-x)$ is decreasing and hence either $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(-x) = M$ or $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(-x) = -\infty$. Considering each alternative we can see that we have the following two possibilities:

- $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\{f(x) - f(-x)\} = L - M > 0$
- $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\{f(x) - f(-x)\} = \infty$

But this contradicts the fact $\lim_{x \to \infty}\{f(x) - f(-x)\} = 0$. Note that in the above we must have $L > M$ because $f(x)$ is strictly increasing ($\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(-x) = M \leq f(0) < f(1) \leq L = \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$).

**Update**: From OP's comment below I guess further explanation is needed which I provide below. First I would advise OP to convince himself of the following result:

> *If $f(x)$ is increasing on interval $[a, \infty)$ then either $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ exists or $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.*

There is a counterpart for decreasing functions:

> *If $f(x)$ is decreasing on interval $[a, \infty)$ then either $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ exists or $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to \infty$.*

You can see the following examples $f(x) = -1/x, \arctan(x)$ for the increasing case with existing limits and $f(x) = \log x, e^{x}$ for diverging to $\infty$. Their negatives would serve as examples for the decreasing case. The function $f(x) = \cos x$ mentioned in comments by Hurkyl is not increasing and hence the above result does not apply to it. Once you are convinced to some extent by the above examples it is time to prove the result. I will establish the case for increasing function. So here goes the proof.

Let $f(x)$ be increasing on $[a, \infty)$. Clearly we can have only two possibilities: either $f$ is bounded on $[a, \infty)$ in which case $\sup_{x \in [a, \infty)} f(x) = A$ exists and is finite or $f$ is unbounded on $[a, \infty)$.

If $f$ is bounded I will show that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = A$. Clearly since $A = \sup f(x)$ for any given $\epsilon > 0$ there is a number $x_{0} \in [a, \infty)$ such that $A - \epsilon < f(x_{0}) \leq A$. Since $f$ is increasing therefore if $x > x_{0}$ we get $A - \epsilon < f(x_{0}) \leq f(x) \leq A$. It follows that we have $$A - \epsilon < f(x) < A + \epsilon$$ for all $x > x_{0}$ and hence $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = A$.

If $f$ is unbounded then for any given positive number $N$ we have a value $x_{0} \in [a, \infty)$ such that $f(x_{0}) > N$. Again if $x > x_{0}$ we get $f(x) \geq f(x_{0}) > N$ and thus we have $f(x) > N$ for all $x > x_{0}$. It follows that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.

There is another issue which OP is facing and that is regarding split of limits in case of expressions like $f(x) \pm g(x)$ when $x \to \infty$. Clearly the rule $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\{f(x) \pm g(x)\} = \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) \pm \lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)$$ holds when both the limits $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)$ exist. *What happens when either one or both of them don't exist?* In case one of them exists (say $\lim_{x \to \infty}g(x)$) then the behavior of $\{f(x) \pm g(x)\}$ as $x \to \infty$ is same as that of $f(x)$ as $x \to \infty$. When both the limits don't exist then we have only one case when we can say with guarantee and that is:

*If $f(x) \to \infty$ and $g(x) \to \infty$ then $f(x) + g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$.*

Similar remarks can be made when the limits are $-\infty$.

Comment: from what i understand to split the limit that is given to two limits like L and M we must be sure that they exists .... and here we cant be sure (f(x)=cos(x) is good counterexample given by Hurkyl in the comments )

Comment: @BorisMorozov:I am not splitting in that way. The case when both $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ tend to $L,M$ should be clear to you. Consider other case when $f(x) \to\infty$ and $f(-x)\to -\infty$ as $x \to\infty$. In this case clearly $f(x) - f(-x) \to \infty$. Same way we deal with other cases and find that the difference $f(x) - f(-x)$ tends to $\infty$ as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @BorisMorozov: I have updated my answer with more detailed explanation of the results I have used.