# Does all non-monotonic continues functions have $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$?

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, proof-verification

Given $f\colon\mathbb{R}  \to \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and the $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ does not exists . show/prove formally that there exists $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$

My strategy is showing that $f$ is not monotonic function because all monotonic functions have limits when $x \to \infty$ ( $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=l$ while $l \in \mathbb{R}$ or $l=+/- \infty$ ) now i can say that there exists $x_1$ and $x_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_1)<0$ and $f'(x_2)>0$ and use the mean value for derivative function (Darboux's theorem)

Can i really say that a continuous function is not monotonic just because $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)$ does not exists ? or its a "one way" statement ?

does all non-monotonic continues functions have $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x_0)=0$ ?

Comment: Edited because $f(x_0)'$ is the derivative of the constant $f(x_0)$.

Comment: What about $f(x)=2x+\sin x$? (This is with regards to the question in the first paragraph not the one in the title).

Comment: @Boris, in your definition, $\lim=\infty$ counts as $\exists$ or not?

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla yes it does . so i guess its not a counterexample. and thanks for editing

Comment: This is  a subquestion of question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691042/displaystyle-lim-x-to-inftyfx-f-x-0-show-that-fx-0-0 asked only a little while ago.

Comment: its not the same (lol i asked the same question yesterday http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688635/formal-proof-from-calulus looks like he too have a calculus exam tomorrow :D) in this question the limit does not exists ... while in the one you sent me it could be function that converges to some limit l at -$\infty$ and l' at $\infty$ and $l=l'$ or a function like f(x)=cos(x) that does not converge to any limit .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. Then $f'(x)$ is of constant sign so that either $f(x)$ is strictly increasing (in which case $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) = L, \infty$) or $f(x)$ is strictly decreasing (in which case $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x) = L, -\infty$). You get a contradiction in any case. Also see [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/688635/formal-proof-from-calulus/689399#689399) to one of your earlier questions.

Comment: so my version of the proof is more or less ok ? and we can say that all continues non-monotonic functions have a point at which the derivative is zero ? thanks .

Comment: yeah i think so...

Comment: @BorisMorozov Unless we assume differentiability of $f$, it is not true. See for example $\arcsin( \sin x )$.

Comment: @Adayah: differentiability of $f$ is a given hypothesis in question. See first sentence of the question.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I was answering the question in the above comment, not the question in the Original Post. The differentiability assumption (nor any other) doesn't implicitly carry over.